# HTTP BASIC AUTH + IIS + NTLM + PHP Logout Script

Tags: php, http, iis, ntlm

I have the following configuration:

IIS + NTLM + HTTP Basic AUTH + PHP.

Everything is fine except that there is no way to logout a user....
The way http://test@localhost.com doesn't work I think because of NTLM.
Is there a way to successfully logout?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: what are you doing to long in user ?

Comment: To login user I use HTTP Basic Authentication